# Use column, but ignore data in column

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has bad indexes, and I am building a php page where you can fill in any of the fields and it will give you results based on what was filled in. Here is the query I want to run. The problem is that there are no indexes on just `fname`

```
select * from members where 1 and fname = 'Ryan' limit 30
```

To get my query to use an index, I need to add `lname` to the query. What I don't know, is how to add it without it doing anything (if that is even possible).

```
select * from members where 1 and lname = '{ANYTHING}' and fname = 'Ryan' limit 30
```

I used `{ANYTHING}` as a placeholder to mean, well any value. Doing this will use an index, but how do I tell mysql to ignore what is in that column for a search (if possible)?

Comment: Are you wanting to accept either no value or some value? Meaning return all rows or filtered? If so I would short circuit with a variable (e.g. (@MyLname IS NULL OR lname=@MyLname) where @MyLName is a parameter.

Comment: How would adding a last name that you dont' know and then using a wildcard search help improve the search?  (is the index a composite index on last name THEN first name?) if so, why not build an index JUST on first name?

Comment: `lname like %`, but I doubt it'll help you.

Comment: its index is `(lname, fname)`, and I can't add indexes to the table at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your index is on `(lname,fname)` and you don't know `lname`, then the index is essentially useless for the kind of query you are doing.

This makes sense if you think about it - the index is ordered first by `lname` then by `fname`.  Without `lname` there is no way to find a given `fname` in the index without just scanning the entire thing, which of course defeats the purpose of using an index in the first place.

It would be like finding all the Johns or Erics in the phone book (which is "indexed" by last name then first name).  Without a last name to go by, knowing the first name is useless or at least no better than scanning the entire phone book.

Also, a ref to the MySQL docs, from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html)

> MySQL cannot use an index if the columns do not form a leftmost
> prefix of the index. Suppose that you have the SELECT statements shown
> here:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1;
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col1=val1 AND col2=val2;
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col2=val2;
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE col2=val2 AND col3=val3;
>
> If an index exists on (col1, col2, col3), only the first two queries
> use the index. The third and fourth queries do involve indexed
> columns, but (col2) and (col2, col3) are not leftmost prefixes of
> (col1, col2, col3).

Comment: true but shouldn't he be able to use part of the index, at least the name part?

Comment: @Mark - Added my phone book example to illustrate why that doesn't work.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: shouldn't the index be `(fname, lname)` since same first names are more common the same last names?

Comment: @Ryan - That would depend entirely on how you do your queries.  I would probably have two separate indexes, one on just `fname` and another on just `lname`.

Comment: @EricPetroelje, I see your point. It's because our search doesn't form a leftmost prefix since the lname would essentially be a wildcard. Is that right?

Comment: @EricPetroelje, sorry still trying to understand this. Based on the explain, it seems like MySQL will perform a full index scan for the lname but will be able to use part of the index (range).  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ef93/3

Comment: @MarkBasmayor - When you have `WHERE lname is not null` then technically it could do a range scan - but the range to be scanned would be all the rows where lname is not null.  So depending on how many non-null lnames there are, you might get better performance than a full table scan.  But I also didn't see anything in his question where he wanted to exclude rows with a null value in the lname column either

Comment: @EricPetroelje, ahh I see so that's where the range scan is coming from. You got my vote. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Well boo, I guess it is just going to have to be slow until the new database is designed. At least this is for the company internal website so only a few people will use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE lname is not null AND fname = 'Ryan'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ef93/3

Comment: right, I didn't take out the where 1 part, pls see revised answer

Comment: @RyanNaddy do you have null values in your lname column?

Answer (score 0):

At once I think probably you want this. If not we'd rethink :-)

```
select * from members where 1 and lname LIKE '%' and fname = 'Ryan' limit 30
```

Comment: like's don't use indexes, indexes need to have equality

Comment: @Ryan Naddy, not true, a LIKE statement will be able to use an index if the wildcard is at the end i.e. LIKE 'Doe%'

Comment: @MarkBasmayor Ah, yes you are correct, but with this query it is at both the beginning and end, so it doesn't use the index.